# Regex to identify JSON in a String to split using : separator

Tags: java, json, regex, string, split

I have an input String which is being split using `:` (colon) as separator. This String can contain all string values OR possibly a json object itself as part of this incoming string.

For example:

*Case#1:* **123:HARRY_POTTER:ENGLAND:MALE**

*Case#2:* **123:HARRY_POTTER:[{"key":"City", "value":"LONDON"}]:MALE**

There is code in place that uses `str.split(":")` which is handling the case#1, but for case#2 since the json part of the string contains `:` (which are to be ignored while splitting), the program breaks.

I need a regex that could (1) identify the json in string and (2) a regex that would not split if `:` is preceded and followed by `"` (`":"`) as it appears in JSON string.

So if the string is identifed to contain json i can use `str.split(<regex-to-split-string-with-json>)`

**I arrived at these regex to match for a `"` preceding to `:` none of which are working unfortunately:**

Negative Look Behind:  `(?<!\"):` and `(?<!\")[:]`

Positive Look Behind: `(?<=\"):` and `(?<=\")[:]`

Please suggest!

Comment: I think this is too complex for regex.  Using regex for parsing is often a bad idea.  Get a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Please try regex `(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9\\]]):` its working as expected for your both the cases:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "123:HARRY_POTTER:[{\"key\":\"City\", \"value\":\"LONDON\"}]:MALE";
        String regex = "(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9\\]]):";
        String arr[] = str.split(regex);
        System.out.println("Length: " + arr.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Length: 4
[123, HARRY_POTTER, [{"key":"City", "value":"LONDON"}], MALE]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example data, perhaps it would be enough to either match from `[` till `]` or match any char except `:`

But as this data comes in mixed, it is not easy to determine what is actual valid json. You would still have to validate that afterwards.

Note that this is a brittle solution, and does not take any nesting of the square brackets into account.

```
\[[^]\[\r\n]+]|[^\r\n:]+
```

- `\[[^]\[\r\n]+]` Match from `[...]`
- `|` Or
- `[^\r\n:]+` Match 1+ times any char except `:` or a newline

See a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/TdJ8za/1) and [Java](https://ideone.com/UgFsHI) demo.

Example

```
String regex = "\\[[^]\\[\\r\\n]+]|[^\\r\\n:]+";
String string = "123:HARRY_POTTER:[{\"key\":\"City\", \"value\":\"LONDON\"}]:MALE";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
123
HARRY_POTTER
[{"key":"City", "value":"LONDON"}]
MALE
```